# JS : Two intervals at the same time / Avoid a specific error message in the console

Tags: javascript, console, setinterval, typeof, clearinterval

I'm running an interval that is checking every 250ms, if a specific element is already defined.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
if(typeof data !== 'undefined') {
    clearInterval(interval)
    console.log('data is ready'); myscript; ;
}}, 350);
```

This works perfectly fine, but I have two challenges.

1) In the console I get: `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property...` while the interval is running...How can I avoid/mute the error during the script is running and checking if the data is defined

2) I'd like to run another interval, that checks if some other data is  defined and fires another script. I just duplicated the script from above, changed `typeof data` and `myscript` and put it below the script from above. But if run the scripts, the second interval doesn't stop. Even if `data2` is already defined.

How's that possible?

All input is appreciated!

Comment: why would that code throw an error? What is trying to read the undefined variables? 2) are you using the same variable names??